# Book (first in a series?) with a teenage witch attending a school of magic mainly with nonhumans

Tags: story-identification, novel, witches

I'm 99% certain I read this as a Kindle book in 2019, but I think I acquired it before that. The main character is a witch, with her mother and sister having the same abilities. She wasn't great at magic, being bad at remembering the properties of herbs. Her mother was more accomplished. Her sister... I think her sister was trying to leave the world of magic behind, although I think the protagonist was still trying to figure out why. Both girls attended a school for magic which was largely nonhuman, something which I think was wearing on the sister.

At the start of the book, there's a new girl, whose parents are vampires. The new girl was not yet, but the circumstances of her parentage essentially left her permanently anemic. They head to a ghost town to, well, see the ghosts, and photograph them, I think for a club. The main character fashions a charm to attract the ghost, which works too well. An elf that knows the main character shows up to the rescue.

Later, there's a dance at someone's manor. The elf guy is there. One of the main character's human friends at the school gets kicked out for breaking the peace after attacking the new girlfriend of the boy who just broke up with her. Oh, and there was a kitsune boy who was obviously crushing on the main character, who also went to the school.

I think I left off reading it to pick up a library book, and just never quite got back to it.

Comment: Apparently 'kitsune' is a kind of legendary creature from Japanese folklore - a fox that can transform into human form. In case that helps anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a troll through my Kindle library, specifically looking for witch stories, I think this is Kristin S. Walker's *[Small Town Witch](https://pattyjansen.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/first-series-free-small-town-witch-kirsten-s-walker/)*.

> Teen witch Rosamunde is totally mature and responsible—if only her mother would realize that. Then she could learn more advanced spells, get her parents to listen to her opinions, and finally go on a date with that cute boy from school. But her mom is stricter than all the other magical parents in town, and Rosa is fighting an uphill battle for her independence.
>
> But there’s strict, and then there’s the crazy spells Rosa finds hidden around the house, including one that can track Rosa’s every movement. Suspecting her mom’s magic use has gone too far, she enlists the help of her friends to find the full extent of her mother’s control and any way to break free of it. Yet some secrets are best left hidden—and truth about her family, if she can find it, might threaten everything Rosa has ever known.

The [reviews on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/18164133-small-town-witch) mention the fae party, her family, the kitsune in her class, and her friend descended from vampires.